# How to fix the no audio device installed message?

Tags: windows, audio

I'm facing a problem with the audio on my PC.

I just got back from a three week-long trip, and when I came back I noticed that the audio wasn't working. It said that there's "no audio device installed." I thought this was strange because it was working perfectly fine before I left.

Anyway, I tried all of the methods suggested on the Internet. None of them worked. I tried opening the device manager to "uninstall and reinstall the driver," but I didn't find a device for the audio at all (as most of the Internet posts suggested I would).

I tried to open `services.xx` (I forgot the extension) and checked whether the audio settings were correct, and they were correct.

I tried reformatting my computer (it was about time for it anyway) and upon completion I noticed that there still was no audio device installed.

What other ways could there be? This is really strange and I'm beginning to think that someone may have done something while I was away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried opening the device manager to "uninstall and reinstall the
>   driver," but I didn't find a device for the audio at all ... I tried
>   reformatting my computer ... here still was no audio device installed.

This means (almost for sure) that the audio hardware has failed. Since you reinstalled Windows, starting in Safe Mode or like will not help.

If the audio device is a separate card, power off and re-seat the card and try again.

If this fails, try a local repair shop

Comment: When I use the troubleshooter, I constantly get the message that restarting the computer will update the driver and solve it or something. I restart the computer, and I keep getting the same message.

I guess I need to take it to the repair shop after all.

Comment: Yes, I think so - you have a hardware problem